# Correlation between the dependent variable and the instrument

Tags: instrumental-variables

In the case of a single endogenous variable and a single instrumental variable, the IV estimator is given by

$b_{IV} = \frac{cov(z,y)}{cov(z,x)}$

It is often mentioned that "the instrument should not affect the dependent variable directly, but only through the endogenous variable". But if the instrument should not affect the dependent variable directly,

$cov(z,y) = 0$

would hold, making

$b_{IV} = 0$.

So what is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short/Technical Answer**:

It's untrue that $cov(y,z) = 0$ whenever $z$ does not directly affect $y$. The key is the word "directly". We hope to find an instrument such that "z influences x which influences y". This would mean that $cov(y,z|x) = 0$ (that is, if we observe the value of $x$, knowing $z$ tells us nothing incremental about $y$), but it does *not* mean that $cov(y,z) = 0$ unconditional on $x$.

**Long/Intuitive Answer:**

The distinction you need to make here is the difference between an **associative** (or correlative) effect and a **causal** one.

Let's first look at an example (linked at bottom). Suppose you want to know how the **size of a political protest ($x$)** causally affects **local political outcomes ($y$)**.

However, if you simply look at the *association* between $x$ and $y$, you may note a number of potential issues. For example, the size of the protest ($x$) could itself be correlated with other factors like the importance of the issue or the likelihood of the protest causing change. These factors are also correlated with $y$. Hence, they confound the relationship between $x$ and $y$.

So how can an instrument variable help us? Consider the instrument of **how good the weather was on the day of the protest ($z$)**. The intuition is that **weather ($z$)** could directly impact **crowd size ($x$)**; however **weather on the day of a protest ($z$)** should not *directly* influence a **local political outcome ($y$)**. The only way you would expect $z$ and $y$ to be related is *through* $x$.

Example Source: https://dash.harvard.edu/bitstream/handle/1/13457753/TeaParty_Protests.pdf

Comment: Thanks for this very good answer. So $cov(y,z|x) = 0$ means that z does not affect y conditional on x. This then implies that $cov(y,z) \neq 0$ because z can affect x and x can affect y.

Comment: Meanwhile, perhaps we should add that cov(z, y | x) = 0 also implies that z does not affect y through u.